# Python executable importerror

Tags: python, compilation, exe, py2exe, importerror

I have a gui that I created with wx and a bunch of other libraries like matlabplot, win32api etc...

I have compiled the python code into an executable using py2exe.

The executable gets created but when I try to run it, it produces an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "guiupdater.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "paramiko\__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "paramiko\transport.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 70, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\extern\__init__.pyc", line 61, in load_module
ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

I had previously compiled the executable and had it running in a different environment. I'm on a new environment now, but I have all the same dependencies installed etc...

I did some quick research and lots of people say reverting their setuptools to 19.2 version fixed it for them but I am relunctent to do that because my setuptools is at version 28.2. I feel like it would do more harm than good...

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and as I did not want to go far back with versions I had to do some research...

Problem is that while processing `pkg_resources.extern` all necessary modules from (private?) default package `pkg_resources._vendor` are not found (delayed load).

Compare contents of `pkg_resources._vendor` at source (site-packages) and inside *library.zip* that is generated with executable. Whatever is missing in zip can be included by `options` for `py2exe`.

`options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs",...], ...`

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue introduced with newer versions of setuptools.  Either:

add 'pkg_resources' to setuptools.setup packages option

or

Downgrade to version 19.2

```
pip install setuptools==19.2
```